# Unable to update DB by form data

Tags: servlets, jdbc

please give me advice! I get form data in servlet and try to update the database, but it doesn't works. There is connection with database (without servlet code any data is properly added in db), but no any exception are thrown. The servlet get parameters - they are available in JSP by EL-expressions. I tried to update the db simply by statement, without using preparedStatement but it didn't help. Here it is the code:

```
public class ServletClass extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        DBConn dbConn = new DBConn();
        String number = req.getParameter("number");
        String amount = req.getParameter("amount");
        String date = req.getParameter("date");

        ArrayList list = dbConn.returnList(number, amount, date);
        req.setAttribute("attr", list);
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(req, resp);
    }
}


public class DBConn {

    public ArrayList<InvoicesBean> returnList(String number, String amount, String date) {
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        ArrayList<InvoicesBean> beanList = new ArrayList<InvoicesBean>();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ved", "root", "1111");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into invoices values(?, ?, ?);");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, number);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, amount);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, date);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM invoices;");
            while (resultSet.next()){
                InvoicesBean invoicesBean = new InvoicesBean();
                invoicesBean.setNumber(resultSet.getString("number"));
                invoicesBean.setAmount(resultSet.getString("amount"));
                invoicesBean.setDate(resultSet.getString("date"));
                beanList.add(invoicesBean);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (resultSet != null) resultSet.close();
                if (statement != null) statement.close();
                if (connection != null) connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return beanList;
    }
}
```

InvoiceBean-class is just a standard bean class with getters/setters

Comment: did you check if the date is inserted in the database using a mysql client? also debug your code and check if the resultset has any value, maybe the problem is on your jsp that is not showing the data

Comment: Yes, the data inserted through mysql command line and if I update table from std java class. ResulSet has values - I checked it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 invoicesBean.setNumber(resultSet.getString("number"));
            invoicesBean.setAmount(resultSet.getString("amount"));
            invoicesBean.setDate(resultSet.getString("date"));
```

You can not have the database column names as 'number' or 'date'. they are reserved.
check the column names again. 
for checking if this is the error, you can replace the column names by column numbers 1,2,3.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that is good point. I alredy got that it is better to use number of columns) But the real problem was in IDE (IntellijIDEA). It hadn't deploied jdbc-driver to the project. Now that is Ok.